# Asking Wh- Questions

Tags: wh-questions

I have to write Wh- Questions based on the given sentences.

E.g.
Q: You want to know where the post office is.
A: Where's the post office?

Consider the following question:
Q: Find out when your exam will start.

I was wondering whether the answer is
"When does my exam start?" or "When does your exam start?"

One more question:
Q: Find out how she goes to the office.

Is it "How does she go to the office?" or "How do you go to the office?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really about learning English, but about "jumping through the hoops" that your teacher has set.

If you didn't give the example, then there would be no way to answer this.  There is no English idiom or grammar here.

But in the example, it is clear that "you" means "Pooma Chandra R". It is clear that when the task says "you" you need to use "me".  So if the task is to find when *your* exam starts you use "When does *my* exam start?"

But "She" is a third person, and so a task about "she" should use "she": "How does she go to the office".

I don't think there is anything special about English in this context. The task seems to be to learn to invert the subject and verb when asking a question.  If that's the case, it doesn't matter if you use "you" or "she", provided you make the inversion.  In other words, if you want to know for sure what the grading criteria are, the only way to find out is to ask your teacher (or submit work and have it marked)

Comment: That's what I thought, but there was one more question:
Q: Find out how far is your father's office from your home.

Comment: Good question.  You'll need to answer it and submit your answer to your teacher. Good luck

Comment: Thank you @james